# How to filter list of objects that doesn't match some condition in another list of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have an array of objects of optional working hours of some business (5 min jumps).

In addition, I have an array of objects of appointments.

I want to filter the optional working hours if there is an existing appointment between those hours.

**I tried this solution with moment.js library:**

```
  const optionalWorkingHours = [
    { from: "05:00", to: "05:05" },
    { from: "05:05", to: "05:10" },
    { from: "05:10", to: "05:15" },
    { from: "05:15", to: "05:20" },
    // ....
  ];

  const appointments = [
    { from: "05:00", to: "05:05" },
    { from: "05:30", to: "06:00" },
    { from: "07:50", to: "08:00" }
  ];

  const availableHours = optionalWorkingHours.filter((o) => {
    const optionalFrom = moment(o.from, "HH:mm");
    const optionalTo = moment(o.to, "HH:mm");

    return appointments.some((c) => {
      const currentFrom = moment(c.from, "HH:mm");
      const currentTo = moment(c.to, "HH:mm");

      const isBusyHours =
        currentFrom.isSameOrAfter(optionalFrom, "hour") &&
        currentTo.isSameOrBefore(optionalTo, "hour");

      return !isBusyHours;
    });
  });
```

**Current result:** Duplicated available working hours

**Expected result:** Array of available working hours that don't overlap with appointments array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy, but your check in `.some()` it wasn't complete in my opinion.
Can you try whit that solution:

```js
const optionalWorkingHours = [
  { from: "05:00", to: "05:05" }, // no
  { from: "05:05", to: "05:10" },
  { from: "05:10", to: "05:15" },
  { from: "05:15", to: "05:20" },
  { from: "05:20", to: "05:25" },
  { from: "05:25", to: "05:30" },
  { from: "05:30", to: "05:35" }, // no
  { from: "05:35", to: "05:40" }, // no
  { from: "05:40", to: "05:45" }, // no
  { from: "05:45", to: "05:50" }, // no
  { from: "05:50", to: "05:55" }, // no
  { from: "05:55", to: "06:00" }, // no
  { from: "06:00", to: "06:05" }, //
  // ....
];

const appointments = [
  { from: "05:00", to: "05:05" },
  { from: "05:30", to: "06:00" },
  { from: "07:50", to: "08:00" }
];

const availableHours = optionalWorkingHours.filter((o) => {
  const optionalFrom = moment(o.from, "HH:mm");
  const optionalTo = moment(o.to, "HH:mm");

  const check = appointments.some((appointment) => {
    const appointmentFrom = moment(appointment.from, "HH:mm");
    const appointmentTo = moment(appointment.to, "HH:mm");

    const isBusyHours =
      (optionalFrom.isSame(appointmentFrom) && optionalTo.isSame(appointmentTo)) ||
      (optionalFrom.isSame(appointmentFrom) && optionalTo.isBetween(appointmentFrom, appointmentTo)) ||
      (optionalFrom.isBetween(appointmentFrom, appointmentTo) && optionalTo.isSame(appointmentTo)) ||
      (optionalFrom.isBetween(appointmentFrom, appointmentTo) && optionalTo.isBetween(appointmentFrom, appointmentTo))


    return isBusyHours;
  });

  return !check;
});

console.table(availableHours);
console.log(availableHours);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much. your solution is working